# Make Linux load specific driver for given device (Realtek NIC)

Tags: drivers, realtek

This is a driver issue on a vintage machine (AMD K8, Nvidia chipset) running Linux 3.11 (Mint distro, but I don't think it matters).

```
claudius ~ # uname -a
Linux claudius 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
claudius ~ # lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: NVIDIA Corporation nForce3 250Gb Host Bridge (rev a1)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation nForce3 250Gb LPC Bridge (rev a2)
00:01.1 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation nForce 250Gb PCI System Management (rev a1)
00:02.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation CK8S USB Controller (rev a1)
00:02.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation CK8S USB Controller (rev a1)
00:02.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation nForce3 EHCI USB 2.0 Controller (rev a2)
00:05.0 Bridge: NVIDIA Corporation CK8S Ethernet Controller (rev a2)
00:08.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation CK8S Parallel ATA Controller (v2.5) (rev a2)
00:0a.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation nForce3 Serial ATA Controller (rev a2)
00:0b.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation nForce3 250Gb AGP Host to PCI Bridge (rev a2)
00:0e.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation nForce3 250Gb PCI-to-PCI Bridge (rev a2)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV34 [GeForce FX 5200] (rev a1)
02:05.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

I want the kernel to load an alternative driver for my Realtek 8169 PCI ethernet card, which you can see it at the end of the  list as `02:05.0`. Here's the detail:

```
claudius ~ # lspci -s 02:05.0 -vv -nn
02:05.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8169] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8169/8110 Family PCI Gigabit Ethernet NIC [10ec:8169]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
    Region 0: I/O ports at e800 [size=256]
    Region 1: Memory at febffc00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at febc0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0-,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
```

The issue is that the `r8169` simply doesn't work. It may even make Linux crash. I blacklisted it in `/etc/modprobe.d/`.

The solution seems to be [using the `r8168` driver instead](http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Installation_des_r8168-Treibers). (There's also a [related question on this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108952/27995).) You can download the source from Realtek, compile and install it, which I did. If you `modprobe r8168`, it loads fine but doesn't associate with the hardware, so the card doesn't show up in `ifconfig`.

I think this has to do with the `modalias` (encodes the hardware info) and the device/driver mapping in `/lib/modules/*/modules.alias`.

```
claudius ~ # cat /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000\:00\:0e.0/0000\:02\:05.0/modalias 
pci:v000010ECd00008169sv000010ECsd00008169bc02sc00i00
```

This is my card. Here's the Realtek driver mappings in the system:

```
claudius ~ # grep r816 /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/modules.alias
alias pci:v00001186d00004300sv00001186sd00004C00bc*sc*i* r8169
alias pci:v000010ECd00008169sv*sd*bc*sc*i* r8169
alias pci:v000010ECd00008167sv*sd*bc*sc*i* r8169
alias pci:v00001186d00004300sv00001186sd00004B10bc*sc*i* r8168
alias pci:v000010ECd00008168sv*sd*bc*sc*i* r8168
```

I tried adding this line to the end of the file (knowing that you're not supposed to make manual edits):

```
alias pci:v000010ECd00008169sv000010ECsd00008169bc02sc00i00 r8168
```

Then unloaded and reloaded `r8168` but that doesn't configure the card and there's nothing in `dmesg`.

What's the proper way to map my NIC to the `r8168` driver? Do I have to rebuild the driver so it claims it can handle my card? Or is there some config data I have to add in the proper place?

Comment: Look here for experimental driver for rtl8169 https://sourceforge.net/projects/network-card-driver/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can force a device to use a certain device using bind. If the device is already owned by a different driver, you first have to unbind it.

If a PCI vendor ID (`10ec` for Realtek) and device ID combination is not recognized, you can make it get recognized at runtime with:

```
# echo 10ec 8169 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8169/new_id
```

Example:

```
# lspci -s 04: -nnvvv
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8129 [10ec:8129] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Coreco Inc RTL8111/8168 PCIe Gigabit Ethernet (misconfigured) [11ec:8129]
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 3
        Region 0: I/O ports at c000 [size=256]
        Region 1: Memory at f7b40000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at f7b00000 [disabled] [size=256K]
        Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 1
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=55mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Kernel driver in use: pci-stub

# echo 0000:04:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/pci-stub/unbind
# echo 0000:04:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8169/bind
# lspci -s 04: -nnvvv
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8129 [10ec:8129] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Coreco Inc RTL8111/8168 PCIe Gigabit Ethernet (misconfigured) [11ec:8129]
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 32 (8000ns min, 8000ns max), Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
        Region 0: I/O ports at c000 [size=256]
        Region 1: Memory at f7b40000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at f7b00000 [disabled] [size=256K]
        Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 1
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=55mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: I'm getting 
`-bash: echo: write error: No such device`
Any idea why this is occurring?

Comment: @FitzWatson It might indicate the the device was not actually bound to the specified driver. You can use `lspci` as described in the answer to learn which driver is bound to the device.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. (See below.)

I wouldn't have lost so much time had I not ***jumped to conclusions***. I had a RTL8169 PCI network card to which Linux assigned the [kernel tree `r8169` driver](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/R8169.html). This driver is dysfunctional for my PCI RTL8169 and may even crash the system. I then found the Hetzner page (see link in question) and assumed the advice to use the Realtek `r8168` applied to my situation. (It did not.) When the driver wouldn't associate with my card I stubbornly thought there should be a way to make it do so in order to get the card working. That was a dead-end street.

The solution is to browse the [Realtek site](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/) itself again. They also have a driver called `r8169`, just like the dysfunctional driver from the Linux kernel. I tried that half a year ago. Apparently, it didn't succeed (don't remember exactly); probably due to my ineptitude. Anyway, Realtek released an updated driver in March 2014, and this driver does work! Thank you Realtek!

The happy outcome is the following (using `smbclient`):

```
smb: \> get "Zwölf Uhr mittags.ts"
getting file \Zwölf Uhr mittags.ts of size 4703186788 as Zwölf Uhr mittags.ts
(47839,3 KiloBytes/sec) (average 47839,3 KiloBytes/sec)

smb: \> get "Die heiße Spur.ts"
getting file \Die heiße Spur.ts of size 6841251568 as Die heiße Spur.ts
(48516,1 KiloBytes/sec) (average 48516,1 KiloBytes/sec)
```

I wasn't hoping to get 100 MB/s throughput. The WDC WD800AAJS-00B4A0 harddisk does around 95 MB/s (`dd if=/dev/zero of=test.out bs=8k count=200k`), but first there is a PCI bus (not PCIe!) *shared* bandwidth of 133 MB/s that might affect my setup (see [Gigabit Ethernet: Dude, Where's My Bandwidth?](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/gigabit-ethernet-bandwidth,2321-4.html)), and second, well, the CPU is a trusty old AMD Athlon 64 3200+ single-core from 2003 topping out at 2200 MHz, and it's common in my experience to see Gigabit Ethernet transfer rate significantly reduced by relatively modest CPUs, be it x86/64 or ARM. So 50 MB/s is good enough.

Comment: Hey, I see you have rev10 of the 8169 device. Could you do me a favor and send me a dump of your EEPROM? You need this patch: https://git.lekensteyn.nl/peter/linux/commit/?h=rtl-eeprom-3.13&id=f1b215364763e37243af70e1c4da254a0d2c7ed3. I want to compare it against an older EEPROM dump I have, my card suffers from amnesia which leads to a broken device (advertised as 8129). Please contact me at peter@lekensteyn.nl for more information, I can also provide a datasheet if wanted.

Comment: By the way, for testing network throughput you should use iperf. On one side of the link, run `iperf -s`, on the other one `iperf -c 10.1.2.3` (where `10.1.2.3` the IP address of the server side).