# Script for network restart

Tags: shell-script, networking, ethernet

Sometimes network completely fails  on my server for samba shares (e.g. I could'n connect to server via ssh and samba shares were unavailable). Since there is no working solution to fix it (full description [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323259/r8169-stops-working-after-a-while)) I wrote small script which does network restart and I guess it would help to establish connection. In case If I do **systemctl restart network** it works. So I need that it has to restart  network automatically.

The logic is if gateway is unavailable for ping (*1.121) it will check  another host within LAN. Then if it won't get back response from  the second host it will execute **systemctl restart network**. Can some review and add/remove something  or propose  another way to handle it?

```
#!/bin/bash

ADDR1="192.168.1.101";
ADDR2="192.168.1.5";
ACCS1=$(ping -c 1 -s 1 -w 1 $ADDR1 | grep time | awk -F ',' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}');
ACCS2=$(ping -c 1 -s 1 -w 1 $ADDR2 | grep time | awk -F ',' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}');


if [[ $ACCS1 == 0* ]];
        then
                if [[ $ACCS2 == 0* ]];
                                echo "Host $ADDR2 is unavailable" >> $HOME/blackout_time.log
                        then
                                systemctl restart network
                                echo "Netwotk restart time by script1 - $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%k:%M:%S)" >> $HOME/blackout_time.log
                                sleep 20
                        fi
        fi
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It might be better to expend your effort trying to identify the reason why the network stops in the first place.

Comment: Yes. I made the post about it but still there is no solution that is why I'm asking here

Comment: for once `grep time | awk -F ',' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'`can be shorterned to `awk '/time/ { print $4 }' ` depending on ping status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one compact line:

```
ping 192.168.1.121 -c1 -s1 -w1 -q || ping 192.168.1.189 -c1 -s1 -w1 -q || systemctl restart network
```

Comment: I was about to say "ping return succes/error code don't bother parsing output"

Comment: shouldn't first test be a `||`  according to OP spec ?

Comment: @Archemar: you're right, corrected