# "No rule to make target `clean'. Stop." issue

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, network-interface

Trying to install drivers for NIC and getting error:

```
[root@london r8169-6.023.02]# make clean modules
make -C src/ clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/av/r8169-6.023.02/src'
make -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/home/av/r8169-6.023.02/src clean
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64'
make[1]: *** [clean] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/av/r8169-6.023.02/src'
make: *** [clean] Error 2
[root@london r8169-6.023.02]#
```

So the manual provided by Realtek says:

```
   If you are running the target kernel, then you should be able to do :

                # make clean modules    (as root or with sudo)
                # make install
                # depmod -a
                # modprobe r8169
```

Also tried to execute (from [stackovwerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704764/make-no-rule-to-make-target-clean-stop)):

```
[root@london r8169-6.023.02]# make -f Makefile clean
make -C src/ clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/av/r8169-6.023.02/src'
make -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/home/av/r8169-6.023.02/src clean
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64'
make[1]: *** [clean] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/av/r8169-6.023.02/src'
make: *** [clean] Error 2
[root@london r8169-6.023.02]#
```

**Makefile** is:

```
KFLAG := 2$(shell uname -r | sed -ne 's/^2\.[4]\..*/4/p')x

all: clean modules install

modules:
ifeq ($(KFLAG),24x)
        $(MAKE) -C src/ -f Makefile_linux24x modules
else
        $(MAKE) -C src/ modules
endif

clean:
ifeq ($(KFLAG),24x)
        $(MAKE) -C src/ -f Makefile_linux24x clean
else
        $(MAKE) -C src/ clean
endif

install:
ifeq ($(KFLAG),24x)
        $(MAKE) -C src/ -f Makefile_linux24x install
else
        $(MAKE) -C src/ install
endif
```

Can someone explain where is the mistake ?
Thanks

**UPD1**

```
[root@london r8169-6.023.02]# ls /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64/kerneldrivers/net/ethernet/realtek
8139cp.ko  8139too.ko  r8169.ko
[root@london r8169-6.023.02]# ls /lib/modules/*/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/reatek
/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek:
8139cp.ko  8139too.ko  r8169.ko

/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.2.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek:
8139cp.ko  8139too.ko  r8169.ko

/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek:
8139cp.ko  8139too.ko  r8169.ko

/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek:
8139cp.ko  8139too.ko  r8169.ko

/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek:
8139cp.ko  8139too.ko  r8169.ko
[root@london r8169-6.023.02]#

[root@london r8169-6.023.02]# lsmod | grep r8169
[root@london r8169-6.023.02]#
```

Comment: your kernel already contains `r8169.ko`

Comment: `[root@london src]# lsmod | grep r8169  

[root@london src]#`

Comment: I mean your _kernel package_ `ls /lib/modules/*/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/`

Comment: Please see **UPD1**

Comment: If I remove it manually It won't affect anything. Just tried

Comment: Why don't you use that instead of deleting?

Comment: because of [issue](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323259/r8169-stops-working-after-a-while) with this driver. that is wgy I've decided to install drivers from Realtek.